# Как правильно сделать соответствие полей?

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo

Подскажите как правильно сделать соответствие полей различных сущностей. Например у меня в БД есть таблица со своими полями

```
$db = [
'id', // сгенирированный id
'full_address' // полный адрес
'floorall', // этажность
'build_year', //год постройки
];
```

Есть данные которые приходят мне с определенного API:

```
$api = [
'guid', //так приходи их id но по сути он мне не нужен
'guid_address', //полный адрес
'floor_max', // этажность
'date', //год постройки
];
```

И есть условные рекламные площадки, для которых мне сделать xml-фид, и у них свои требования

```
<internal_id>Это id</internal_id>
<locality>Полный адрес</locality>
<floorall>Этажность</floorall>
<build_date> Год постройки</build_date>
```

Как правильно их сопоставить. По сути это одни и те же данные.
Сделать еще одно таблицу со всеми полями, где колонками будут прописаны сервисы и их название полей?
Или есть какие-то еще способы
P.S.: Навряд ли названия полей будут меняться, но высока вероятность что будут добавляться новые

Comment: входящие поля конвертируете в пхп коде на ваши. Для выгрузки в различные, либо храните таблицу перехода сервис/ваше-поле/их-поле либо то же самое в пхп конфиге. Конфиг вероятно может быт более гибким решением.

Answer (score -1):

абстрагируйтесь от данных.

Допустим, есть такая истина: у вас свои данные, у апи - свои, у площадки - свои.

То, что они совпадают - чистой воды совпадение, не делайте своё приложение, именно с тем, что данные одинаковы.

Сохраните у себя, именно как вам нужно.

P.S если сложно абстрагироваться, представьте, что с API вы получаете совсем другие данные, которые вам ещё нужно будет обработать, и где-то применять

Comment: ну так он это и делает

Comment: @Ипатьев А на сколько такой подход правильный? Просто так сложилось, что рядом нет опытного разработчика, поэтому приходиться все гуглить. Я тоже сначала просто обрабатывал и не парился, но сечас столкнулся с проблемой, что данные могут идти и в обратном направлении. Площадки присылают мне список полей которые нужны для удачного экспорта, если им что-то не хватает. Поэтому я ис просил, можно ли как-то их сопоставить. чтобы я просто обработавал допустим свои поля. А потом просто подменял из на другие. Пусть будут например ключи массива

Comment: @VechoKrainii если в задаче присутствует интерактив с пользователем, то лучше в БД писать соответствие. Я когда-то делал даже интерактивный маппер - показываю структуру XML, и напротив - наши поля, чтобы менеджер сам выбирал привязки. Тут главное помнить что xml бывает не одноуровневый, плюс некоторые знаения идут в атрибутах. Я так и не допилил до конца :)

Comment: @Ипатьев понял, спасибо! Получается отдельная таблица с количеством колонок равным количеству сервисов + колонка с полями бд. и там их прописать? А насчет того что бывает вложенность ничего страшного. Они все вложены и чаще все провожу из в формат одномерно массива чтобы работать удобнне было)

Comment: @VechoKrainii вот такая структура - это всегда кривизна. чтобы добавить сервис понадобится менять структуру базы. Должна быть обычная реляционная структура: таблица сервисов, таблица полей, таблица связок поле-сервис.